# LLDB: Python callback on breakpoint with SBTarget.EvaluateExpression

Tags: python, lldb

I'm trying to execute a Python callback when a certain function is called. It works if the function is called by running the process, but it fails when I call the function with `SBTarget.EvaluateExpression`

Here's my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(void) {
    printf("foo() called\n");
    return 42;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

And here's my Python script:

```
import lldb
import os

def breakpoint_cb(frame, bpno, err):
    print('breakpoint callback')
    return False

debugger = lldb.SBDebugger.Create()
debugger.SetAsync(False)

target = debugger.CreateTargetWithFileAndArch('foo', 'x86_64-pc-linux')
assert target

# Break at main and start the process.
main_bp = target.BreakpointCreateByName('main')
process = target.LaunchSimple(None, None, os.getcwd())
assert process.state == lldb.eStateStopped


foo_bp = target.BreakpointCreateByName('foo')
foo_bp.SetScriptCallbackFunction('breakpoint_cb')

# Callback is executed if foo() is called from the program
#process.Continue()

# This causes an error and the callback is never called.
opt = lldb.SBExpressionOptions()
opt.SetIgnoreBreakpoints(False)
v = target.EvaluateExpression('foo()', opt)
err = v.GetError()
if err.fail:
    print(err.GetCString())
else:
    print(v.value)
```

I get the following error:

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: breakpoint 2.1.
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread 
return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation
```

I get the same error when the breakpoint has no callback, so it's really the breakpoint that is causing problems, not the callback. The expression is evaluated when `opt.SetIgnoreBreakpoints(True)` set, but that doesn't help in my case.

Is this something that can be fixed or is it a bug or missing feature?

Operating system is Arch Linux, LLDB version is 6.0.0 from the repository.

Answer (score 0):

The IgnoreBreakpoints setting doesn't mean you don't hit breakpoints while running.  For instance, you will notice that the breakpoint hit count will get updated either way.  Rather it means:

True: that if we hit a breakpoint we will auto-resume

False: if we hit a breakpoint we will stop regardless

The False feature is intended for calling a function because you want to stop in it or some function it called for the purposes of debugging that function.  So overriding the breakpoint conditions and commands is the right thing to do.

For your purposes, I think you want IgnoreBreakpoints to be True, since you also want the expression evaluation to succeed.

OTOH, if I understand your intent, the thing that's causing you a problem is that when IgnoreBreakpoints is false, lldb doesn't call the breakpoint's commands.  It should only skip that bit of work when we are forcing the stop.